# How can I trigger a click from the console with Cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress

I'm trying to run commands on cypress from the command line. For instance, selecting an element and clicking on it.

I'm trying to do this to try some tests without having to need to run all the previous steps at this point. I'm not sure if this is possible due to the sequential nature of cypress, but it would be really helpful if there was some way to do it. I assumed something like this would be possible from the developer tools console:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="save button"]').click()
```

I'm aware this doesn't work, so I tried with now and then and some other weird strategies. Reading the documentation didn't help. At least the part I read. Any details are appreciated.

--- edit ---

The console is on the same chrome instance that contains the selector playground like shown in in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Artur. Just to confirm, you want to interact with your app via cypress GUI console? In this case you can do it via jquery: `$('[data-test="save button"]').click()` (usually works for me)

Comment: @AlexIzbas  Thanks for the reply! The GUI console is the chrome instance that has the selector like shown in the image I added to the question? I've tried the jquery syntax but returns null although the selector finds the element. Are you using jquery with your site? Mine doesn't have jQuery.